# Redirect URI doesn't match with the one generated with package name and signature hash

Tags: android, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I've already searched too many links but my problem still in pending.

According to documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android I'm try to integrate Microsoft Account in android where user can SignIn through it, but i'm facing issue to signIn user in app. When I run app it shows me an error `com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.msalclientexception: the redirect uri in the configuration file doesn't match with the one generated with package name and signature hash. please verify the uri in the config file and your app registration in azure portal.`

My generated MSAL Configuration was

```
`com.example.microsoftintegrationandroid:host="com.example.microsoftintegration"{
  "client_id" : "0fcce5cd-946f-471b-953a-3948dc69d97e",
  "authorization_user_agent" : "DEFAULT",
  "redirect_uri" : "msauth://com.example.microsoftintegration/A%2FoARUpzRHfPOezOHJootAPRWJ8%3D",
  "authorities" : [
    {
      "type": "AAD",
      "authority_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/7233866a-c721-44ae-b426-6b0e8386199b"
    }
  ]
}`
```

but according to documentation my config file should resemble this example:

```
`{
  "client_id" : "0984a7b6-bc13-4141-8b0d-8f767e136bb7",
  "authorization_user_agent" : "DEFAULT",
  "redirect_uri" : "msauth://com.azuresamples.msalandroidapp/1wIqXSqBj7w%2Bh11ZifsnqwgyKrY%3D",
  "account_mode" : "SINGLE",
  "authorities" : [
    {
      "type": "AAD",
      "audience": {
        "type": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
        "tenant_id": "common"
      }
    }
  ]
}`
```

and in file I've written JSON looks like this

```
`{
  "client_id": "0fcce5cd-946f-471b-953a-3948dc69d97e",
  "authorization_user_agent": "DEFAULT",
  "redirect_uri": "msauth://com.example.microsoftintegration/A%2FoARUpzRHfPOezOHJootAPRWJ8%3D",
  "account_mode": "SINGLE",
  "authorities": [
    {
      "type": "AAD",
      "authority_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/7233866a-c721-44ae-b426-6b0e8386199b"
    }
  ]
}`
```

I can't figure out why this is happening because the config file's content was generated by Azure portal and package name, signature hash, and redirect URI match whatever is shown in the portal.

I'd appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Can you please  mention how you have generated the keystone file and updated in app registration and your code.

Comment: Hi @echo,please let us know if the issue is already fixed or still looking for any solution.

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity I have this project pending.  I will definitely ask for help when needed.  Anyway, no one here has worked with the new API on Microsoft. I can't find any proper tutorial like Facebook and Google Integration.